# what's Python asyncio.Lock() for?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

Is it because coroutines may be preempted in the future? Or it allows people to use yield from in critical section (which IMO shouldn't be encouraged)?

Comment: It's a lock, not sure what it has to do with preemption, when you try to acquire a lock you specifically yield control in hopes it'll be given back to you with you holding the lock. It is in order to have a critical section one coroutine can enter at a time. It's all in the docs.

Comment: I don't think you either read the official docs carefully or understand the question.

Answer (score 122, accepted):

You use it for the same reason you'd use a lock in threaded code: to protect a critical section. `asyncio` is primarily meant for use in single-threaded code, but there is still concurrent execution happening (any time you hit a `yield from` or `await`), which means sometimes you need synchronization.

For example, consider a function that fetches some data from a web server, and then caches the results:

```
async def get_stuff(url):
    if url in cache:
        return cache[url]
    stuff = await aiohttp.request('GET', url)
    cache[url] = stuff
    return stuff
```

Now assume that you've got multiple co-routines running concurrently that might potentially need to use the return value of `get_stuff`:

```
async def parse_stuff():
    stuff = await get_stuff("www.example.com/data")
    # do some parsing

async def use_stuff():
    stuff = await get_stuff("www.example.com/data")
    # use stuff to do something interesting

async def do_work():
     out = await aiohttp.request("www.awebsite.com")
     # do some work with out
   

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(
    parse_stuff(),
    use_stuff(),
    do_work(),
))
```

Now, pretend that fetching data from `url` is *slow*. If both `parse_stuff` and `use_stuff` run concurrently, each will be hit with the full cost of going over the network to fetch `stuff`. If you protect the method with a lock, you avoid this:

```
stuff_lock = asyncio.Lock()

async def get_stuff(url):
    async with stuff_lock:
        if url in cache:
            return cache[url]
        stuff = await aiohttp.request('GET', url)
        cache[url] = stuff
        return stuff
```

One other thing to note is that while one coroutine is inside `get_stuff`, making the `aiohttp` call, and another waits on `stuff_lock`, a third coroutine that doesn't need to call `get_stuff` at all can also be running, without being affected by the coroutine blocking on the `Lock`.

Obviously this example is a little bit contrived, but hopefully it gives you an idea of why `asyncio.Lock` can useful; it allows you to protect a critical section, without blocking other coroutines from running which *don't* need access to that critical section.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Let's me summarize it (for people who don't understand the question).

1) coroutines can't be preempted - they run until "yield from" returns the control back to the loop.

2) asyncio.Lock() is used to protect critical sections that call "yield from" - there is no need to use the lock otherwise.

The discussion is under assumption of single-threaded asyncio usage mode.

Comment: As a good example as dano gave, I have to repeat what I said in the question - I personally don't like the idea of using "yield from" in critical section. It sounds irrelevant but I have to say it.

Comment: dano - In this particular example (keeping in mind that it is indeed contrived), wouldn't you get equivalent performance if you just removed the `yield from` and made a blocking HTTP request? Because with the locking as it is, only 1 instance of `get_stuff()` will ever be in progress. (As in, instance B can only start when instance A has fully completed.)

Comment: @NickChammas If the only coroutines running in the entire application are waiting on `get_stuff`, then the performance would be equivalent. But if you've got other coroutines running other methods that don't need the lock, then no; a blocking HTTP request would block all those other coroutines, completely halting your application until it completes. Using an `asyncio.Lock` allows all those other coroutines to continue to run.

Comment: Ah, yes, and you did point this out at the end of your answer: "...without blocking other coroutines from running which don't need access to that critical section."

Comment: @NickChammas Right. I probably could make that more clear by adding a third coroutine into the example that doesn't call `get_stuff`.

Comment: Since when do coroutines run in parallel?

Comment: @SamanthaAtkins oops,  I used "in parallel" where I should have used "concurrently". Fixed now.

Comment: Thanks.  What I was getting at though is that processes that are not running in parallel, that is at the same time, generally do not require locks.  So I am surprised by locks here.

Comment: @SamanthaAtkins My answer explains why sometimes this is still necessary. Basically, because you can run multiple co-routines concurrently, you could still need synchronization to prevent them from both entering a critical section at the same time. The critical section just needs to be using `yield from` or `await` calls for locking to be necessary in the case of `asyncio`.

Comment: My understanding is that a fundamental difference between co-routines and threads is that two co-routines can never run at the same time within the same process event loop. Think asynchronous logic as in Node.

Comment: @SamanthaAtkins they can't run in parallel, but they can run concurrently. Again my answer gives a use-case where concurrent execution without locking causes unintended behavior.

Comment: Will the third coroutine process waits the `stuff_lock` as well, if it calls `get_stuff`?

Comment: @alper Any coroutine that calls into `get_stuff` will have to wait for the `stuff_lock`.

Comment: @dano I think your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25799576/whats-python-asyncio-lock-for#comment82230073_25799871) resumes perfectly well the explanation of using a Lock (If I understood it correctly). One thing to note on your answer though: `get_stuff` expects an URL, but you don't pass any when calling it. It might help to understand the Lock if you'd pass, say, the same URL on both call?

Comment: @CyrilN. Thanks for pointing that out. I updated my answer.

Comment: Dano, I'm not sure I understood the point of lock, in your example. Both functions will still wait approx. the same, with the main difference that with the lock the load on the server receiving the requests is smaller, since the second request will use cached data.

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea Let's say the request to the remote server takes five seconds. If client one calls the method first, it will wait five seconds. If client two calls the method four seconds after client one, it will wait one second instead of five. As soon as client one gets a response, client two can immediately pull it out of the cache.

Answer (score 5):

one example is when you only want some code run once, yet is requested by many(when in a web app for example)

```
async def request_by_many():
    key = False
    lock = asyncio.Lock()
    async with lock:
        if key is False:
            await only_run_once()

async def only_run_once():
    while True:
        if random()>0.5:
            key = True
            break
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
```

Comment: I think for this to work you'd need to actually instantiate the `asyncio.Lock` object just once and store it in a place where it's accessible by each caller, e.g. as an attribute on some shared object. As is, each call instantiates a new lock and proceeds as if it weren't there.