# Caching data in an API - Handling concurrent/fast requests

Tags: python, api, concurrency

```py
# this is psudo code

cache = {"user_information": response}
async def update_caching(
    app,
    token,
    user_information=None,
    guild_id=None,
    user_guilds=None,
    guild_channels=None,
    guild_data=None,
    guild_roles=None,
):
  if user_information:
    if cache not updated in last 5 seconds:
      response = await request(...) # make request to API
      cache[user_information] = response
  return
```

I have this function to cache results from my api so that I don't have to keep needing to make requests. However, if a user makes the request to this endpoint twice, and the first request has not yet been updated due to it waiting for a request from the API, then there is no data in it. This means that both requests to the api will be sent, causing one to become rate limited.

How can I fix this? I could set the `last_call` datetime before the request is made inside of the `update_cache` function, but then on the 2nd request my API will think that there is data cached, when its not ready yet...

Any tips would be very helpful.

Esentially,
1st request is made, my code is collecting data to cache, but before the new data is ready, the user makes another request to get data - now there are two requests being made to the external thirdparty API and they get rate limited.

I appreciate the code is not functional. But I think it displays what problem I am having.

Comment: Have you considered using a [lock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25799576/whats-python-asyncio-lock-for) for each cache entry? E.g. have one lock per key in your cache, and take the lock before looking at the corresponding cache entry. If it's not in the cache, hold the lock until the request comes back and you insert into the cache. That would prevent concurrent requests for the same user.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll have a look into using lock :)