# What is the point for asyncio synchronization primitives not to be thread safe?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-asyncio

It seems that several asyncio functions, like those showed [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html), for synchronization primitives are not thread safe...
By being not thread safe, considering for example asyncio.Lock, I assume that this lock won't lock the global variable, when we're running multiple threads in our computer, so race conditions are problem.

So, what's the point of having this Lock that doesn't lock? (not a criticism, but an honest doubt)

What are the case uses for these unsafe primitives?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25799576/whats-python-asyncio-lock-for

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Asyncio is not made for multithreading or multiprocessing work, it is originally made for Asynchronous IO (network) operations with little overhead, hence a lock that is only running in a single thread (as is the case for tasks running in Asyncio eventloop) doesn't need to be threadsafe or process-safe, and therefore doesn't need to suffer from the extra overhead from using a thread-safe or process-safe lock.

using Thread and process executors is only added to allow mingling threaded futures and multiprocessing futures with applications running an eventloop futures seamlessly such as passing them to `as_completed` function or awaiting their completion as you would with a normal non-multithreaded asyncio task.

if you want a thread-safe lock you can use a [thread.Lock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Lock), and if you want a process-safe lock you should use a [multiprocessing.Lock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Lock) and suffer the extra overhead.

keep in mind that those locks can still work in an asyncio eventloop and perform almost the same functionality as an [asyncio.Lock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html#asyncio.Lock), they just suffer from higher overhead and will make your code slower when used so don't use them unless you need your code to be Thread-safe or process-safe.

just to briefly explain the difference, when a thread is halted by a thread-safe lock the thread is halted and rescheduled by the operating system, which has a big overhead compared to Asyncio lock that will return to the eventloop again and continue execution instead of halting the thread.

**Edit:** a `threading.Lock` is not a direct replacement for `asyncio.Lock`, and instead you should use `threading.RLock` followed by an `asyncio.Lock` to make a function both thread-safe and asyncio-safe, as this will avoid a thread dead-locking itself.

**Edit2:** as commented by @dano, you can wait for a `thread.Lock` indirectly using the answer in this question if you want a function to work both threaded and in asyncio eventloop at the same time, but it is not recommended to run a function in both at the same time anyway [How to use threading.Lock in async function while object can be accessed from multiple thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63420413/how-to-use-threading-lock-in-async-function-while-object-can-be-accessed-from-mu)

Comment: Using a `threading.RLock` in an asyncio thread when that lock is already held by another thread will block the event loop for as long as you're waiting for the lock, so I wouldn't recommend doing that. In general you should not use any locks directly in an event loop thread other than `asyncio.Lock`.

Comment: You can indirectly wait for a `threading.Lock` from an event loop thread, though, as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63420413/how-to-use-threading-lock-in-async-function-while-object-can-be-accessed-from-mu